iwlwifi driver crashes after the upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS my Wifi became instable und from time to time breaks completetly.
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000000: 08b18086 00100000 02800073 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 40708086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000040: 00020010 10008ec0 001b0c10 0006ec11 10110000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000005 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00104000 00000000 00462031 000031c1 00002000 00000014 40000001
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000120: 0000000f f7c00460 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000140: 14c10003 ffc8d20a 8086f2ff 15410018 00000000 0001000b 0141cafe 00f01e1f
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00104000 00000000 00462031 000031c1 00002000 00000014 40000001
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f f7c00460 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.4) config registers:
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000000: 8c988086 00100407 060400d0 00810010 00000000 00000000 00030300 200000f0
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000020: f7c0f7c0 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 0012010b
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000040: 01428010 00008000 00110000 05323c12 70110040 0024b200 01480000 00000008
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000060: 00000000 00000817 00000000 00000000 00010002 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000080: 00019005 fee01004 00000020 00000000 0000a00d 50011458 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 000000a0: c8030001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00001842 0b118008 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 000000e0: 00003f00 88aa88aa 00000003 00000000 00000050 00000040 08000fb1 05002800
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000100: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00060011 000011c1 00002000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000160: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000180: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 000001a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 000001c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 000001e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.4: 00000200: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Do Dez 19 17:14:59 2024] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5


My Wifi device, driver and firmware is the following:
*-network
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Wireless 7260
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlan0
       Version: 73
       Seriennummer: 80:86:f2:c8:d2:0a
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-51-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode ip=192.168.2.56 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:31 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff


To recover it I must reload the iwlwifi module from the kernel as you can find here.
Is there any fix for this by configuration or installing something? Is maybe Ubunut or the device manufacturer Intel Corporation able to fix this, e.g. by providing a new driver? Can a new kernel update fix this?

In the meantime as a workaround, I have written a bash script which detects the iwlwifi driver outage and then reactivates it:
#!/bin/bash

echo "The iwlwifi recovery tool has been started."
while true
do
    line=$(dmesg -T --since '1 second ago')
    if echo "$line" | grep -q -e " iwlwifi .* enqueue_hcmd failed: -5"; then
        echo Wi-Fi is rebooting 
        modprobe -r iwlwifi 
        sleep 10 
        modprobe iwlwifi 
        echo Wi-Fi established
        sleep 60
    fi
    sleep 4
done

Then I have created, activated and enabled a systemd service so that the above bash script runs automatically.
